# Configuring hadoop-azure abfs driver to authenticate with storage accounts as az CLI user

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to figure out how to configure the [ABFS — Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/abfs.html) driver to authenticate with Azure storage accounts as the user (regular user) logged in via the Azure CLI.

Some context

- We can not use SharedKey, SAS or OAuth (ClientCredsTokenProvider, UserPasswordTokenProvider, MsiTokenProvider) for various reasons, including the need to avoid using shared credentials and also the need to have an audit trail of storage account access that identifies the user in each transaction.
- We can not use Azure Synapse or DataBricks at this time

We were hoping to somehow leverage RefreshTokenBasedTokenProvider.

RefreshTokenBasedTokenProvider needs the following, but I do not know how to easily get these values

- `fs.azure.account.oauth2.refresh.token`
- `fs.azure.account.oauth2.refresh.endpoint` (defaults to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/token")
- `fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id`

I have not been able to find anything in the hadoop docs, the github repo https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-azure or on Microsoft's sites.

The [Azure docs on the ABFS dreiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver#authentication) explicitly say that it is posible to authenticate an end user but don't mention how.

> Microsoft Entra ID OAuth Bearer Token: Microsoft Entra bearer tokens are acquired and refreshed by the driver using either the identity of the end user or a configured Service Principal.

I tried using an access token given by `az account get-access-token`. However, this is an access token rather than a refresh token. Also, I was not sure what client id to use. So, the following error is probably not helpful.

```
'org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException: HTTP Error 400; url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/token' AADToken: HTTP connection to https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/token failed for getting token from AzureAD.; requestId='ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff'; contentType='application/json; charset=utf-8'; response '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff Correlation ID: ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff Timestamp: 2023-11-01 18:17:54Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2023-11-01 18:17:54Z","trace_id":"ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff","correlation_id":"ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"}'
```

SIDE NOTE: I know that it must be possible to authenticate. I have seen that, in Synapse is able to authenticate as the logged-in azure user but I am not able to figure out how this is done. However, the context here does not involve Synapse. We are unable to use Synapse for this work

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/azure-storage.html), these are the ways to connect to ADLS Gen2: 1. OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal. 2. Shared access signatures (SAS). 3. Account keys. You can configure the hadoop-azure abfs driver to authenticate with storage accounts as shown below in Synapse:

Create a Synapse notebook and run the code below to configure:

```
service_credential ="<clientSecret>"
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.adlss.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.adlss.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.adlss.dfs.core.windows.net", "<clientId>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.adlss.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.adlss.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/token")
```

After configuration, you will be able to access the Data Lake storage account. Try with the sample code below:

```
mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<directory>")
```

You will get the output as below:

[image]

Otherwise, without configuration, you can access the storage account by adding the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the user. To add the role, follow the procedure below:

Go to Access Control of the storage account, click on Add, and select Add Role Assignment as shown below:

[image]

Search for the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role, select it, and click on Next as shown below:

[image]

Select the member and click on Review + Assign as shown below:

[image]

After assigning the role, you will be able to access the storage account without any authentication as shown below:

```
filepath = 'abfss://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/inputs/stocplace.csv'  
df= spark.read.csv(filepath, header='true')
display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for such a detailed reply.

Comment: @NaveenSharma as per my previous comment, unfortunately, the answer provided does not address the original question, which mentioned that we can not use Synapse and we want to use credentials of the user currently logged into Azure CLI